# permission.C2D_MESSAGE gcm android package starts with capital letter

Tags: android, eclipse, package, manifest, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem in android manifest package name.
It starts with capital letter.
I am trying to register with gcm but i can't.
Any solution because my application is already uploaded to the play store.

In my manifest i have for example:
 `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="Com.Example" 
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1">`

when i try to give permissions to my package 
`<uses-permission android:name="Com.Example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE">`
  when i try to run my application i am getting INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED .
 My application is already on the playstore so i can't change name package with caps letters to little letters. Please help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "i can't" is a completely useless description of your problem.

Comment: Please provide some source code, the appropriate section of the manifest, and the error report please.